# <MailCore/MailCore.h> File Not Found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mailcore2

I am having an issue with adding the mailcore 2 header file into my xCode project.  I have followed all of the steps from their website:

```
For iOS - If you're targeting iOS, you have to link against MailCore 2 as a static library:
Add libMailCore-ios.a
Add CFNetwork.framework
Add Security.framework
Set 'Other Linker Flags': -lctemplate-ios -letpan-ios -lxml2 -lsasl2 -liconv -ltidy -lz -lc++ -stdlib=libc++ -ObjC
Make sure to use LLVM C++ standard library. Open Build Settings, scroll down to 'C++ Standard Library', and select libc++.
In Build Phases, add a Target Dependency of static mailcore2 ios.
```

I added the 'mailcore2.xcodeproj' xCode project from the cloned 'build-mac' mailcore2 folder on my desktop.  In build phases, I added 'static mailcore2 ios (mailer2) to the target dependencies under the build phases section in xCode.  In the 'Link with binary libraries' section, I added 'Security.Framework', 'CFNetwork.framework', and 'libMailCore-ios.a'.  Finally, in Build Settings, I added the 'other linker flags'
 -lctemplate-ios -letpan-ios -lxml2 -lsasl2 -liconv -ltidy -lz -lc++ -stdlib=libc++ -ObjC

and I since the project already used the standard c++ library of 'libc++', I just left it that way.

I entered my the following into my ViewController.h:
 and I got the error shown below:

```
'MailCore/MailCore.h' file not found.
```

I have been trying to find a solution for days now, but I have come up with no solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance to all who reply.

***BTW: I am using the language 'Objective-C' for this project.  I have trouble-shooted with the issues page on github, as well as MailCore's main website.  All of the 'solutions' didn't fix the xCode error I was presented with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're missing including 'MailCore' in your Targets 'Header Search Path' Build Setting.

According to https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore, you need to

> Under your app’s target, switch to Build Settings. Locate “Header
>   Search Paths” in the Build Settings and add
>   "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../include"

[image: 'Header Search Path' Build Setting]

You can set this by doing the following:

1. Find out the path on disk to your the the 'MailCore' library headers
2. Select your Target, then the 'Build Settings' tab and scroll down to 'Header Search Path'
3. Double tap the existing value test (or blank entry if none)

[image: Editing Header Search Path]

4. When the Window appears, click the '+' to add a new line, then enter "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../include" (in double quotes).
5. Change the second column from 'non-recursive' to 'recursive' to ensure Xcode will search recursively for headers.

Then compile your app and you should hopefully see that the header is now found.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  When you say, 'MailCore' library, are you referring to the cloned mailer folder, or the build-mac folder?

Comment: I'm referring to the folder which contains the headers for the MailCore library. When you acquired the library, it should have also been distributed with a folder containing headers for the library. 

I just updated my Answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MailCore in particular. However your compiler error specifically mentioned 'MailCore/MailCore.h'. As a result your code is expecting a folder called 'MailCore' to exist, and contain a header called 'MailCore.h'. Where this 'MailCore' folder is is where you want to set the path to.

Comment: ok.  thank you.  I'm assuming that's within the build-mac folder.  If it doesn't work, I'll try using another folder instead. :)

Comment: Actually, I found the specific 'Header Search Path' configuration from this website: https://github.com/MailCore/MailCore. I've updated my answer based on this.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but xCode still gives the same error.  I added both the directory you gave me, as well as the one containing my header files and set them both the recursive.  Not sure what's going wrong...

Comment: What instructions did you follow for the other setup steps? Can you share a reference? Also can you share a screenshot of your 'Header Search Path' settings, and compile error you get?

Comment: I appreciate all of your help! Suddenly, the error disappeared when I tried to compile it.  Would you still like a screenshot?

Comment: np problem. If you don't mind accepting my answer it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi @GlenT , I'm a newbie in xcode and I'm using Xcode 6.3.2. From your answer above, I can't find 'Header Search Path', all I have only 'Always Search User Path' and 'Framework Search Path'. I really stuck on this problem, any help will be good for me. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnHexis check you haven't filtered out all the fields here. There is the 'Basic', 'Advanced' etc filters up top. That might be hiding these fields.

Answer (score 0):

NOTHING LIKE ABOVE HELPED!!!!

This may help you, it solved my 'MailCore/MailCore.h' not found:

My project with MailCore2 would build just fine (so DEBUG mode is functioning just right), but when archiving it for AdHoc distribution (that uses RELEASE config) it would suddenly say 'MailCore/MailCore.h' not found!!! wth ikr.

I just went in derived data and found this path to the libraries and headers for the DEBUG config (BTW, both AdHoc and Release folders were there but empty!!!):

(you can get to that folder from Organizer\Projects\ choose you project and partial Derived Data path will be displayed, click on the right arrow to go to the folder in finder)

/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Developer/XCode/DerivedData/YOURAPPNAME-SOMERANDOMLETTERS/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/

copied it and added (in both PROJECT and TARGETS Build Settings) to:

1. Header Search Paths for my Archive Config (MAKE IT RECURSIVE)
2. Library Search Paths for my Archive Config (MAKE IT RECURSIVE)

So find that path and add it to the config that you want and make it recursive.

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Thank you!!! I was searching for a solution to this problem for a month! My program would only work in debug mode, but when it was set to release, I would get that same error! I'll let you know if your solution solves my problem.  Thanks again!

Comment: @iProgramIt: so you need to add this path to Release lines, i.e. configs for those search paths